# Free Bug Tracker in .NET

Tags: .net, bug-tracking

Is there any good bug tracker based on .NET which is free?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Two bug trackers I know:

- [BugTracker.NET](http://www.ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html)

> BugTracker.NET is a free, open-source,
>   web-based bug tracker or customer
>   support issue tracker written using
>   ASP.NET, C#, and Microsoft SQL Server
>   (or its free cousin, SQL Server
>   Express).

- [BugNET](http://www.bugnetproject.com/)

> BugNET is an issue tracking and
>   project issue management solution
>   built using the ASP.NET web
>   application framework. Email
>   notifications, reporting and per
>   project configuration of fields and
>   values allows efficient management of
>   bugs, feature requests, and other
>   issues for projects of any scale.

Comment: +1 for BugNET!  What a great project.

Comment: http://www.bugnetproject.com/ not found

Comment: Found it at https://github.com/dubeaud/bugnet

Comment: BugNet now is off

Comment: I tried to use BugNet recently.. lots of missing files.. things haven't been very easy to deploy and implement. When I got things to where I wanted to be, there were essential stored procs that weren't included in the system so I had to give up. It looked great, but unfortunately it hasn't been updated and it's plagued with a lot of open issues that aren't being addressed.

Answer (score 4):

[Countersoft](http://countersoft.com/) offers a free license for up to 5 users for their product [Gemini](http://countersoft.com/). I think they also have a free license for open source projects.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net issue tracker is a simple alternative.
You can download it from http://www.asp.net/downloads/archived/starter-kits/issue-tracker/

Answer (score 0):

Some commercial ones will let you use them for free if you're just one developer. [Axosoft](http://www.axosoft.com) will give you a free single user license to their OnTime software. (Although I found it to be overkill for me personally.) [SourceGear's Fortress](http://www.sourcegear.com/fortress/) issue tracking software is also [free for single users](http://www.sourcegear.com/faq.html#singleuser).