# Free ASP.NET Issue Tracker

Tags: asp.net

Are there any free [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) Issue trackers around? I tried [BugTracker.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BugTracker.NET) but any others will be a great help.

Comment: just to clarify: are you looking for a bug tracker or an issue tracker? And are you looking for tracker written in ASP.NET or for ASP.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used IssueManager from UltraApps.  It is free, and open source.

I've actually used it at two of my prior employers.

http://www.ultraapps.com/app_overview.php?app_id=20

Answer (score 8):

http://www.bugnetproject.com/

Answer (score 3):

Hai rowmark,

BugTracker.NET [Here it is](http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html)

or have a look at this [BugLOG](http://forums.asp.net/t/1364840.aspx)

This is simple and FREE bug logging application. For a small or big company, or open source project start testing , the biggest problem to find simple, easy to use Bug logging system.

or a similar question in stackoverflow
[Free Bug Tracker in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197125/free-bug-tracker-in-net)

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is the open source [BugZilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/), but I am currently trying and really like FogBugz. They even have a [student/startup](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/StudentAndStartup.html) version for free.

For a large list of issue trackers, check out the [Comparison of issue tracking systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue_tracking_systems) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

Using BugNet for for the past 2-3 years. It's simple and powerful.

Comment: I like bugnet as well. Installation on a shared host was very easy