# Mantis bugtracker alternative

Tags: php, .net, mantis

I really like how Mantis bugtracker works, and for some personal projects already using it.

But there is a small issue. For the company i work for, i also wanted to use Mantis Bugtracker, but the company does not want to support PHP, because Dot Net is the standard within the company.

So now i am looking for a decent alternative for Mantis Bugtracker, but one that is running in dot net.

Or are there other solutions that i might throw in, to get mantis somehow supported in dot net?

Comment: Not using an application (where you do not actually need to develop things for) just because it uses language X is stupid... Expect to pay lots of money for a .net-based alternative as that kind of software is usually not free in the .NET/Java world.

Comment: imo its strange they dont want to support php in the company, but im bound to the regulations (unless i get some good arguments) but dont want to pay for a .net alternative. Would very much like some free alternative for mantis, that is as decent as mantis is. Plus i just cant think of any good reasons why a company would not want to support PHP. but i know to less of security issues that might raise ?

Comment: @ThiefMaster, Dante1986: The company policy is not relevant for the question

Comment: @jgauffin, yes it is. that is the whole reason for asking this here. If Php was supported, it wouldnt need asking. But if tehre is a a way to run mantis in .Net somehow, i might be able to pursue them (with some luck).

Comment: An old question, but the answers may still be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197125/free-bug-tracker-in-net

Comment: @jgauffin: That's why it's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @jgauffin, thanx for that link. i found that first one already but the GUI of that one wasn't what i was looking for. the second in the post looks already way better, and might is what i was looking for.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: What kind of value did you want to add to the q&a with your comment? It just moves the focus from the question. I bet that dante already have tried to make the management to change their mind.

Answer (score 3):

The comapny policy is utterly relevant.

In an ideal world it wouldn't be but people always worry about "WHAT IF..." what if it goes wrong, can I support it .. is there support.. will my technical team know how to fix it. All of these will help an IT manager put the kybosh on developments dreams of say JIRA (java based) in a .net shop.

There are solutions to this.

You can try to suggest you get a hosted solution atlassian and others offer deals like this where they do all support and you just consume the service, usually big alarms ring about privacy however and data going outside the company etc.

One of the better solutons that is mostly .net based is [fogbugz](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/)

I have always told management that if you want to be absolutely safe you either get a product which is free that you can get third party support for or has a commercial version or you just get a well known product thats well supported (who cares what its written in if it works and has professional support).

Unfortunately some managers/dev managers do and its just not worth the argument after a while they usually aren't listening and do not want to be convinced no matter how right you are.

Comment: Exactly the problem im currently experiancing: We do not support php, because our standard is .NET. And there ends the discussion at the moment. I tried the argument of external hosting (very cheap for the company) but putting files on external hosted servers seems to be against pollicy even more...

Comment: You are fighting a loosing battle my friend